# How do I return a Promise from a TypeScript interface?

Tags: javascript, typescript

This is my interface

```
declare module ISteeplejack {

    export interface IRealtimeStrategy {
        onConnect: (event: string) => any;
        send: (event: string) => any;
        use: (namespace: string) => any;
    }

}
```

I can use this interface in my classes fine, eg:

```
export class Realtime {
    protected _strategy: ISteeplejack.IRealtimeStrategy
}
```

However, I want the three interface methods to return a Promise.  When I put a promise in my interface how I would inject it, it fails to compile

```
declare module ISteeplejack {
    export interface IRealtimeStrategy {
        onConnect: (event: string) => Promise<any>;
        send: (event: string) => Promise<any>;
        use: (namespace: string) => Promise<any>;
    }
}
```

---

```
/path/to/steeplejack/lib/realtime.ts(32,39): error TS2305: Module 'ISteeplejack' has no exported member 'IRealtimeStrategy'.
/path/to/steeplejack/lib/realtime.ts(42,48): error TS2305: Module 'ISteeplejack' has no exported member 'IRealtimeStrategy'.
```

How do I define the interface so that I can tell the interface to return a Promise?

I have got both the es6-promise npm package and typings definition installed as well.

---

**Update**

Have put an example on [Cloud9](https://ide.c9.io/riggerthegeek/tmp) to illustrate. If you run `npm run build` you'll see the problem.  Take out the `Promise<any>` in the interface and replace with `any` and it compiles fine.

Comment: According to the error message it doesn't look like there's a problem with Promise classes. Could you make a demo eg. here? http://www.typescriptlang.org/Playground

Comment: The error isn't with the Promise, but it gets that whenever I use a concrete class (rightly, I think). But I can't work out how to import Promise interface from es6-promise typings. Demo - http://bit.ly/1OlRaly

Comment: I just added a dummy Promise class definition and it doesn't show any errors. http://bit.ly/1QQHnpu

Comment: I think your example works when you have everything in a single file. When you start splitting it out, I get problems.  Have set up in Cloud9 https://ide.c9.io/riggerthegeek/tmp (public, but will need GitHub/BitBucket). Run `npm run build` and you get the same error I get. Take out `Promise<any>` in the interface and it's fine

Comment: I'm trying to open the project on Cloud9 but never used that before... anyway I think the problem is you can't "trick" ts that you are returning a Promise, you actually must return a Promise as defined in the interface. (as I see you are returning void)

Comment: Yes, the reason I can't return the promise because it's a concrete class and that's got no business being in an abstract interface.  How do I import the es6-promise promise interface into my interface?

Comment: @RiggerTheGeek what version of ES are you compiling to?

Comment: ES5. If you look at the Cloud9 example, it's got the full compilation options on there